# UIScrollView scrollRectToVisible: nor contentOffSet: working

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview

```
[_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake((page - 1) * 500, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
```

I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled and with a width of 500 points. I want to set the page to number 2 but it doesn't work. I know the x Coordinate is 500 because I NSLogged it. I've read that disabling the paging enabled feature fixes it but it would defeat the purpose in this case. How do you fix the issue?

Comment: Did you try to see if it works with paging enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((page - 1) * 500, 0) animated:NO];
```

If that doesn't work you should probably check if page == 2 is actually true.

Comment: I realised the problem was that I was using a method called setPage with that line of code, and using NSLog i found that the view did load method was called after I set the page.